# groups of different size randomly selected within different classes

Tags: r, grouping, sample

i have such a difficult question (at least to me) that i spend 2 hours just writing it. Complete impossible to program it by my self. I try to be very clear and i´m sorry if i didn´t. I´m doing this in a very rustic way in excel, but i really need to program this.
i have a data.frame like this

```
id_pix id_lote clase   f1   f2
45       4      Sg    2460 2401
46       4      Sg    2620 2422
47       4      Sg    2904 2627
48       5      M     2134 2044
49       5      M     2180 2104
50       5      M     2127 2069
83      11      S     2124 2062
84      11      S     2189 2336
85      11      S     2235 2162
86      11      S     2162 2153
87      11      S     2108 2124
```

with 17451 "id_pixel"(rows), 2080 "id_lote" and 9 "clase"

this is the "id_lote" count per "clase" (v1 is the id_lote count)

```
 clase   v1
1:     S 1099
2:     P  213
3:    Sg  114
4:     M  302
5:   Alg   27
6:    Az   77
7:    Po  228
8:   Cit   13
9:    Ma    7
```

i need to split the "id_lote" randomly within the "clase". I mean i have 1099 "id_lote" for the "S" "clase" that are 9339 "id_pixel" (rows) and i want to randomly select 50 % of "id_lote" that are x "id_pixel"(rows). And do this for every "clase" considering that the size (number of "id_lote") of every "clase" are different. I also would like to be able to change the size of the selection (50 %, 30 %, etc). And i also want to keep the not selected set of "id_lote". I hope some one can help me with this!

here is the reproducible example

this is the data with 2 clase (S and Az), with 6 id_lote and 13 id_pixel

```
id_pix  id_lote clase   f1  f2
1       1        S    2909  2381
2       1        S    2515  2663
3       1        S    2628  3249
30      2        S    3021  2985
31      2        S    3020  2596
71      9        S    4725  4404
72      9        S    4759  4943
75      11       S    2728  2225
218     21       Az   4830  3007
219     21       Az   4574  2761
220     21       Az   5441  3092
1155    126      Az   7209  2449
1156    126      Az   7035  2932
```

and one result could be:

```
id_pix  id_lote clase   f1  f2
    1       1        S    2909  2381
    2       1        S    2515  2663
    3       1        S    2628  3249
    75      11       S    2728  2225
    1155    126      Az   7209  2449
    1156    126      Az   7035  2932
```

were 50% of id_lote were randomly selected in clase "S" (2 of 4 id_lote) but all the id_pixel in selected id_lote were keeped. The same for clase "Az", one id_lote was randomly selected (1 of 2 in this case) and all the id_pixel in selected id_lote were keeped.

what colemand77 proposed helped a lot. I think dplyr package is usefull for this but i think that if i do

```
df %>%
group_by(clase, id_lote) %>%
sample_frac(.3, replace = FALSE)
```

i get the 30 % of the data of each clase but not grouped by id_lote like i need! I mean 30 % of the rows (id_pixel) were selected instead of id_lote.
i hope this example help to understand what i want to do and make it usefull for everybody. I´m sorry if i wasn´t clear enough the first time.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should really think about creating a reproducible example.

Comment: Please don't copy/paste answers to your question in order to comment. Please use facilities designed for that under the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First glimpse I'd say the `dplyr` package is your friend here.

```
df %>%
group_by(clase, id_lote) %>%
sample_frac(.3, replace = FALSE)
```

so you first use `group_by()` and include the grouping levels you want to sample from, then you use `sample_frac` to sample the fraction of the results you want for each group.
As near as I can tell this is what you are asking for.  If not, please consider re-stating your question to include either a reproducible example or clarify. Cheers.

to "keep" the not-selected members, I would add a column of unique ids, and use an anti-join `anti_join()`(also from the dplyr package) to find the id's that are not in common between the two data.frames (the results of the sampling and the original).

---

### ## Update ##

I'm  understanding better now,  I believe.  Think about this as a two step process...
1) you want to select x% (50 in example) of the id_lote from each clase and return those id_lote #s (i'm assuming that a given id_lote does not exist for multiple clase?)
2) you want to see all of the id_pixels that correspond to each id_lote, all in one data.frame

I've broken this down into multiple steps for illustration, not because it is the fastest / prettiest.

raw data: (couldn't read your data into R.)

```
df<-data.frame(id_pix = c(1:200), 
           id_lote = sample(1:20,200, replace = TRUE),
           clase = sample(letters[seq_along(1:10)], 200, replace = TRUE),
           f1 = sample(1000:2000,200, replace = TRUE),
           f2 = sample(2000:3000,200, replace = TRUE))
```

1) figure out which id_lote correspond to which clase - for this we use the dplyr `summarise` function and store it in a variable

```
summary<-df %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(clase, id_lote) %>%
  summarise()
```

returns:

```
Source: local data frame [125 x 2]
Groups: clase

   clase id_lote
1      a       1
2      a       2
3      a       4
4      a       5
5      a       6
6      a       7
7      a       8
8      a       9
9      a      11
10     a      12
..   ...     ...
```

then we sample to get the 30% of the id_lote for each clase..

```
sampled_summary <- summary %>%
  group_by(clase) %>%
  sample_frac(.3,replace = FALSE)
```

so the result of this is a data table with two columns, (clase and id_lote) with 30% of the id_lotes shown for each clase.

2) ok so now we have the id_lotes randomly selected from each class but not the id_pix that are associated with that class.  To accomplish this we do a `join` to get the corresponding full data set including the id_pix, etc.

```
result <- sampled_summary %>%
  left_join(df)
```

The above makes a copy of the data set a bunch, so if you have a substantial data  set you could just do it all at one go:

```
result <- df %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(clase, id_lote) %>%
  summarise() %>%
  group_by(clase) %>%
  sample_frac(.5,replace = FALSE) %>%
  left_join(df)
```

if this doesn't get you what you want, let me know and we'll take another crack at it.

Comment: when i did what you proposed i get the 30 % of the data of each clase but not grouped by id_lote like i need! I mean 30 % of the rows (id_pixel) were selected instead of id_lote. i hope the example help to understand what i want to do and make it usefull for everybody. I´m sorry if i wasn´t clear enough the first time. Do you figurate how to do it?

Comment: I've got a solution just need to write it out when I get back in front of a computer. 30 min...

Comment: The {anti_join()} was also precise to keep the non selected id_lote!